# Get all distinct column values beside column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I want to get all unique column values besides the column name(ignoring the null values).
The dataframe that I have:

```
value1   value2  value3

ab       gh      mn
ab       lk      tu
ba       ag      ga
gf       cv      null
```

The dataframe that I want :

```
columns           value
value1            ab,ba,gf
value2            gh,lk,ag,cv
value3            mn,tu,ga
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just pass `pandas.Series.unique` as aggregate to `pandas.DataFrame.agg`:

```py
>>> df.agg(pd.Series.unique)

value1         [ab, ba, gf]
value2     [gh, lk, ag, cv]
value3    [mn, tu, ga, nan]
dtype: object
```

If you want them as string instead of list, and without the `NaN` values as you have in the expected output, you can filter out `NaN` values and join them:

```py
>>> df.agg(pd.Series.unique).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i for i in x if pd.notna(i)))

value1        ab, ba, gf
value2    gh, lk, ag, cv
value3        mn, tu, ga
dtype: object
```

If needed, call `to_frame` pass the column name, and reset the index, and rename the index column:

```py
(df.agg(pd.Series.unique)
 .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i for i in x if pd.notna(i)))
.to_frame('value')
.reset_index()
.rename(
    columns={'index': 'columns'})
)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  columns           value
0  value1      ab, ba, gf
1  value2  gh, lk, ag, cv
2  value3      mn, tu, ga
```

Comment: I am getting error : Arrays must be of same length

Comment: Please copy, paste above code and run it. You should not get error on above code. I tested it again, and it is working fine!

Comment: It is still giving me the same error : ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: What python and pandas version are you using?

Comment: python - 3.7.3, pandas - 0.24.2

Comment: Ya, sorry, that will give all the values, for unique, try this: `df.stack().reset_index(level=-1).drop_duplicates().groupby('level_1').agg(list)`